# Page by refresh/visit positioning left at 4:3 aspect

Tags: html, css

I've created a website [click here to go to the website](http://www.parfumerievleuten.nl)

it looks well on a 16:9 screen, but on a 4:3 screen, when I want to visit the website, de page is positioning left, it's very weird.
Which HTML or CSS code do I need to fix this problem?

Comment: It's positioned ridiculously far to the right at every resolution - even on a 1920px wide browser it's way off. I completely don't understand what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: Also please read: *[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)*.

Comment: here on my imac 21,5" it works well, but on a MB Pro Retina 13", it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS.

You set the pictures to be to be positioned like: (example is `header1.png`)

```
element.style {
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 1400px;
}
```

This means `1400 px` plus the width of the picture, `800 px`, which gives a total of `2200 px`. This means a 4:3 screen simply isn't wide enough. Instead of using `absolute`-positioning  you center you content in a dynamic way (screen size wont matter):

```
center.content {
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto:
}
```

You can play around with this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3dLxy/).